# auto-layout in GraphStream, node position

Tags: java, autolayout, graphstream

I am using GraphStream, to generate some graphs.

**I have following questions:**

> 1. When I use auto-layout in the library, is it possible for me to obtain the position information of each node?
> 2. Can I change the type of edge? e.g. the default edge type is solid line. Can I change edge into dash line, or other type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question I would advise you check the GraphStream website and especially the [FAQ on the subject](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/FAQ/The-graph-viewer/Why-node-positions-do-not-update-when-I-move-them-in-a-viewer/).

For the second question, see the [visualisation tutorial](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation_1.1/) as well as the complete [CSS reference](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/GraphStream-CSS-Reference_1.2/).